# C, How to get the program to not skip through scanf() when using fork()

Tags: c, scanf, fork

The program needs to take ten inputs, this is too happen simultaneously while other processes happen, using fork(). Instead it just goes "Enter input:

Enter input: Enter input: Enter input:Enter input: Enter input: Enter input: Enter input: ..."

```py
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{ 

  int n1 = fork();
  int n2 = fork();
  if (n1 == 0 && n2 > 0 ){
     getMarks();
  }
  else if (n1 > 0 && n2 == 0){ 
     printf("child2")
  }

  else if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0){
     printf("Parent");
  }
  else {
     printf("Child3");
  }



}

void getMarks(){
    printf("Enter ten marks: \n");
    int i = 0;
    int highestMark = 0;
    for (i; i < 10; i++){
        int num = 0;
        printf("Enter Mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num > highestMark) { 
            highestMark = num; 
        }

    }   
    printf("Highest Mark is : %d", highestMark);

}
```

The expected result would be for the other childs and parent to print into the console, while also being able to give input into getMarks()

Answer (score 0):

Uggh don't do that then.

Your first character of entry got sent to the shell. Your second character of entry got sent to the program. `scanf` can't recover from input errors very well.

To avoid this problem, don't read standard input from child processes whose parent isn't alive anymore. Arrange your code so this doesn't ever happen.